# How to use Typescript with Redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Currently in Redux reducer as a typescript type for `action` I'm using `any`. What should I replace `any` since using it is a bad practise?

I tried to use `Action` type by importing `import { Action } from "redux";` but then I get errors as `Property 'homePageMovies' does not exist on type 'Action<any>'.` and equivalent to this for other action types.

reducer:

```
import { 
    ADD_HOME_PAGE_MOVIES,
    CHANGE_SELECTED_MOVIE, 
    IS_MOVIE_PAGE_OPENED,
    SEARCHED_MOVIE,
    CURRENT_PAGE
} from "./actions";

const initialState = {
    homePageMovies: [],
    selectedMovie: 0,
    isMoviePageOpened: false,
    searchedMovie: '',
    currentPage: 1
  }

function rootReducer( state = initialState, action: any ){
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_HOME_PAGE_MOVIES:
            return {
                ...state,
                homePageMovies: action.homePageMovies
            }
        case CHANGE_SELECTED_MOVIE:
            return {
                ...state,
                selectedMovie: action.selectedMovie
            }
        case IS_MOVIE_PAGE_OPENED:
            return {
                ...state,
                isMoviePageOpened: action.isMoviePageOpened
            }
        case SEARCHED_MOVIE:
            return {
                ...state,
                searchedMovie: action.searchedMovie
            }
        case CURRENT_PAGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                currentPage: action.currentPage
            }
         default: 
            return state;
     }
}

export default rootReducer;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

What should I replace `any` with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can give it `AnyAction` type instead:**

Something like this:

```
import { AnyAction } from 'redux'

interface CounterState {
  value: number
}

const initialState: CounterState = {
  value: 0
}

export default function counterReducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: AnyAction
) {
  // logic here
}
```

Comment: Yours suggested solution of using `AnyAction` works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Generally we officially recommend using the official Redux Toolkit, especially with TypeScript, as it massively reduces the amount of TypeScript types you will have to write in the first place and is heavily geared towards inference-style TypeScript. Questions like this will not come up there.

As for how little TypeScript is involved, take a look at the first example [on this api documentation page](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) and switch between the TS and JS tab and look for the differences.

If you want to get started with this, you can [go here for a quick comparison](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) and then best follow the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).

As for TypeScript-specific setup instructions, see the [TypeScript QuickStart docs page](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript)

PS: I know this is not the answer to the question, but usually people ask this question because they are following horribly outdated tutorials instead of the official documentation and I want to make those aware of it.